# Elasticsearch, how to fix "No active shards"?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have logstash + elasticsearch + kibana setup for indexing logs. For some reason es stopped indexing the the data and I had to kill the running es instance and restart it. Typically when I did restarts, es will come up without problem. But now es not searchable using kibana.

What I see using es tool is that one index is not assigned anywhere.

```
logstash-2013.07.22 4 r UNASSIGNED
logstash-2013.10.05 0 r UNASSIGNED
logstash-2013.10.05 0 p UNASSIGNED
logstash-2013.10.05 1 p UNASSIGNED
logstash-2013.10.05 1 r UNASSIGNED
logstash-2013.10.05 2 r UNASSIGNED
logstash-2013.10.05 2 p UNASSIGNED
logstash-2013.10.05 3 r UNASSIGNED
logstash-2013.10.05 3 p UNASSIGNED
logstash-2013.10.05 4 p UNASSIGNED
logstash-2013.10.05 4 r UNASSIGNED
```

And of course when I search using kibana, the query fails to search on this index.
I don't see any error in elasticsearch.log.

I have only one node running ES, though my default configuration has 1 replica configured.

Comment: what is the output of _cluster/health ?

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue with my LS+ES 3 node cluster, I used the following to fix the unassigned shards.

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/_cluster/reroute' -d '{
  "commands": [
    {
      "allocate": {
        "index": "INDEXNAME",
        "shard": "SHARDNUMBER",
        "node": "PICKANODE",
        "allow_primary": 1
      }
    }
  ]
}'
```